# Spring data jpa findOne throwing IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException exception

Tags: java, database, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa and made a repository extending JpaSpecificationExecutor. Then I use findOne(specs) method. But I am getting this exception:

```
IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 2
```

Specs query does return more than one result, but I thought using findOne will return the first result? But I still receive error. I think I am using the wrong method. Which method should I use to get the first result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

findOne method assumes that your query will return only one row. So results that return more than one row will throw exception. Instead you can use findAll(...).get(0)